# Stripe modelling prices that are a % of revenue of customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a case where customers that use the product generate revenue with it and a small percentage should be paid to my company in return.

I wonder how to model that in stripe. If all customers would make their revenue in the same currency I could setup a usage based price in EUR that reflects the percentage and for each customer generated revenue could create a UsageRecord with an amount that represents the revenue e.g. EUR-Cent like with below code.

However I have customers with multiple currencies and thus their revenue comes in multiple currencies too. And then I cannot use the approach as the UsageRecord just states an amount but not currency. And the amount*pricePerAmount in Currency is specified in the UsagePrice. Thus I would report amounts in a different currency which with this approach would be considered to be in EUR - i.e. that wouldn't work.

```
 const record: Stripe.UsageRecord = await this.stripe.subscriptionItems.createUsageRecord(subscription.stripeUsageSubscriptionItem,
            {
               quantity: order.customerPrice * 100,
               timestamp: Math.trunc(order.createdDate.getTime() / 1000),
               action: 'increment',
            },
            {
               idempotencyKey: idempotencyKey
            }
);
```

Also I dont want to create a price item for each currency and apply the UsageRecord to that price since I would need to create lots of such prices(one per currency).

Or should I jsut for each customer order create a paymentintent with the right amount sort of manually?

Weird thing to me is that Stripe itself charges the same way i.e. percent of revenue we make over it - so they somehow can do it right?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Why does the currency matter if you're taking a percentage? You're confused on some level. Or the question is written on a confused premise.

Comment: The problem is that usage based prices in Stripe have currency attached and the UsageRecord has just an amount and amount (of usageRecord) * pricePerAmount (of UsagePrice) then gives the amount charged in the currency of the UsagePrice. Hope that's clear now? Also tried to improve the overall question.

Comment: You don't have to create a price/currency in advance. you could always use the [price_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items-price_data) in order to create the prices on the go

Comment: I understand. However this still seems to polute the set of prices pretty much and in case a customer once has revenue in EUR and once in CHF I have an issue unless I craeted both prices at start - meaning I have to know up front right - which I probably cannot ensure.

Comment: In the end I opted to attach the % of revenue to the fixed price the customer pays and thus each subscriotion will have one price item and whenever the customer has revenue created then calculate the anount in EUR based on exchange rates for which I created another service and create a new inoviceitem which denotes both the referenceId to the incoming revenue event as well as the orice and currency of the original revenue.